# Ubuntu: command line app to convert office documents to PDF

Tags: excel, ubuntu, pdf-generation

Is there any command line app in Ubuntu that can convert Office documents to PDF, like convert Excel (xls,xlsx) and Word(doc, docx) to pdf in Ubuntu. I cannot used any Office suite, like Open Office.

I know that there are Java projects that can communicate with OpenOffice to use its functionality to convert documents to PDF, but not going in direction.

But if the OpenOffice people or LibreOffice people have created a stand-alone command-line app with this capability to covert documents to PDF, I would like that very much.

Comment: Do you consider using docker instance with the LibreOffice installed to do the job?

Comment: Hi, I have not considered using Docker here. Good to be aware of this in general, so thanks for this Ryan. But I don't want another service running, taking up lots of memory. SO as I have said, I am looking for a solutions that does not involve LibreOffice.

Answer (score 5):

**Step - 1**
Install **Libreoffice**.if it is not install in your system or server.

do follow:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf your_file_path --outdir upload_directory
```

Here,

> **your_file_path** : complete your file path like /var/www/mydocument.docx
>
> **upload_directory** : complete directory like /var/www/

Comment: Hi Umesh, I am looking for a solution that does NOT require OpenOffice or LibreOffice to be installed on the server. I have very clearly stated that NO Office suite of any kind to be installed. So you have not answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

1.Download `CutePDF` writer

then

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

2.Set the writer as your default printer.

3.Place all your `.doc` files in the same folder

Then run:

```
oowriter -pt pdf your_word_file.doc
```

you'll find your .pdf file in ~/PDF.

Comment: Hi there, I know about CutePDF for windows. Is this CutePDF you mention the same as cups-pdf you are referring to in the sudo apt-get. I see that you also use 'oowriter' command, that looks like one is using OpenOffice functionality. If you look at my restrictions, one cannot make use of OpenOffice.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, when I mentioned a command line app from OpenOffice, what I was asking was if the  OpenOffice community created another application, besides open office, that just has the printing capability only in a separate stand alone application that can be called from commandline. I do NOT want to invoke starting-up any openOffice application such as writer.

Comment: @Palu, Do you find any solution for it?
I mean convert to pdf file without using openoffice and libreoffice.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, still I have found NO solution to this problem. I am just waiting for the day when someone will find a solution!